# Adding infoWindows on Google Maps marker objects

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, cluster-computing, infowindow

I want to add info windows on multiple markers, placed in clusters on google maps. Here is my code below. When I tap on a marker, can not see anything. Have a look please.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 62.601, lng: 29.7636 },
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      title: "test",
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers, "click", function () {
      infowindow.setContent("<h3>" + "testing" + "</h3>");
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  });
  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath:
      "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.map()` you are returning your marker before adding the `EventListener` to it, so it will never be added.

Assuming this is the correct way to add an `EventListener` to a marker, do the following - Temp save it and return it after you added the `EventListener` like in this snippet:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 62.601, lng: 29.7636 },
  });
  var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // temp save
      position: location,
      title: "test",
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () { // add eventlistener to marker
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // probably also move infoWindow initialization in here
      infowindow.setContent("<h3>" + "testing" + "</h3>");
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    return marker; // return after
  });
  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath:
      "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
  });
}
```